# How to ignore line breaks on VSCode search

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is the thing.

I got a VERY LARGE project where i'm working at, and i really need to use the search function of vscode to find where stuff is, where functions are called, where constants are, and so on.

I had a function calling twice where it shouldn't, but after searching on the project every place where it was called, i couln't find it being called twice. The function was `this.form.render()`.

End of story, I found the problem, and it was being called like this:

```
this.form
    .render()
    .then(()=> {...});
```

Anyway, the point is:

When i searched 'form.render' on the searchbox, i couln't find this place where it was being called because of the linebreak. How can i make sure i'm searching EVERY instance where it's being called, regardless of linebreaks?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression. I use https://regex101.com/ to test my expressions.

try this expression: `this\.form[\s\n\r\t]*\.render`

in the above expression you need a `\` in front of the `.` (dot)'s to escape them to search for literal `.`'s.

Also you can use the search workspace tool to search all files

[image: reg expression button in vs code]

Comment: The interesting thing to note here is that ordinarily `[\s\n\r\t]*` would be exactly the same as `[\s]*` but vscode requires the `\n` to be explicitly stated even though `\n` is otherwise matched by `\s`.   So in this case `[\s\n]*` is sufficient.